# android studio sdk messed up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

i'm trying to install android studio. i downloaded it from this link:
`https://r5---sn-p5qs7nzk.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2021.1.1.21/android-studio-2021.1.1.21-linux.tar.gz`.
i also downloaded the sdk from here: `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r33.0.0-linux.zip`.
i untared android studio and in the `bin` folder, i ran:
`chmod +x studio.sh && ./studio.sh` it bringed up the android studio wizard &...
when it got to the sdk part, i couldn't select `android sdk tools`  because it said `(installed)` but it isn't. i know what you might say:
Android Studio comes with the sdk!NO! IT DOESN'T! when i try to change the sdk directory it says:
`Nothing to do! Android SDK is up to date. SDK emulator directory is missing`.
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a Persian Calendar. Or if it is in Persian or Arabic, then you should change that. Set your system language on English (US preferably).